# How to convert CBCharacteristic.value to NSString in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I have been unable to convert CBCharacteristic's value property which is of type NSData to NSString. I tried the usual initWithData:encoding: method of NSString as given below. But it returns nil.

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:characteristic.value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

I am able to see the string value on console when I do NSLog on value directly.

```
NSLog(@"characteristic.value: %@", characteristic.value);
```

Can aanybody give any idea on how to get the string value out of characteristic.value?

Comment: Not all binary data (`NSData`) have a meaning in UTF8 String. You'll probably get nil if you convert `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(someUIImage) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`.

Comment: @Larme: Yes, correct. But in this case it is a known characteristics which has a hexadecimal no as string(uuid format). I am able to see the value of it when I print the data. NSLog(@"characteristic.value: %@", characteristic.value);

Comment: Show us the value and the result you want then.

Comment: It prints. value: <11122334 45566778 899aabbc cddeeff0 00>. This is the default value assigned to the characteristics. I have hardwired this value in my code. If the characteristics has this value then I will have to do some calculation and change the value of it to something else.

Comment: If you just want to check that it's equal, you can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317860/converting-hex-nsstring-to-nsdata to convert the `@"11122334 45566778 899aabbc cddeeff0 00"` as NSString into NSData and do a `isEqual:`.

Comment: Thanks Larm for the easy solution. It works fine.

Comment: If the value is fix, it's maybe faster to use a Byte array instead of all that conversion from string.

Comment: Any idea why I am not able to read the string value from the characteristic as shown below.  NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:characteristic.value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", str);

Comment: Because it's not a valid UTF8 data I guess?

Answer (score 0):

- You need to know what means the NSData. Could be a String, struct, uint32, etc. See here: [core-bluetooth-get-all-features-description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38718841/ios-core-bluetooth-get-all-features-description-from-device/38719661#38719661)
- Is BLevel for battery level? You need to do reverse engineering or read the doc (BLE doc if it's a "known" one, or device doc)